# How do deploy just my static content in Tomcat / Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-deployment

I am doing development of a web app with Java. My current process is to export the project as a WAR to the Tomcat folder, where it picks it up and reloads the WAR. I wait for it to run through its startup process and away it goes.

I would like to make it not need to do an entire reload when it isn't necessary. If I'm making a small change to a single class, perhaps it could reload just that class. If I'm changing static content, perhaps it could just send that HTML file or JS file.

How can I achieve this? My only real dealbreakers is that I need a solution that works with Eclipse. I'd even consider a different container than Tomcat, although it's where I'm familiar.

Comment: Do you have the Web Tools installed? They let you launch Tomcat from within Eclipse and normal builds based on changing resources in the workspace will cause them to be redeployed.

Comment: I had but they had been absolutely destroying my response time. It was better doing outside. Following the steps in Umeshwaran's answer helped significantly, I think in particular the point about unchecking the reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hot reload/deploy your application inside Eclipse , but for seperate Tomcat server , I don't think hot reload is possible .

### For Eclipse

For eclipse , you can follow the instructions in this link https://mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

This will speed up your development , but it has it's limitations

> Hot deploy will support the code changes in the method implementation only. If you add a new class or a new method, restart is still required.

### For Tomcat

I haven't tried  it , but all the class files  of war will be loaded/rendered from binary memory of Tomcat . So try changing the class files in that location(Not sure about the path of binary class folder ) .

But if you want to render static HTML,js and css from tomcat server , it can be easily done adding another folder inside "webapps" folder (eg : /webappps/static)

Comment: I will try the first option when I get home. I don't mind the occasional restart, I just don't want a 90 second dev cycle! I'll report back later.

Comment: If Tomcat's startup time is your main concern, did you check [HowTo FasterStartUp](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp) on Confluence's wiki? Eclipse reloads Tomcat's components intelligently: a change in a class triggers the application reload, more serious changes restart Tomcat.

Comment: The real genius part of this was step 2.2 of the tutorial, `In the Tomcat Plugin page, clicks on the Module view, make sure Auto Reload is Disabled. Default is enabled.` This is what was killing my attempts earlier because it was constantly restarting when I didn't want it to.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I will investigate that - I would love a better startup time, especially for development! I still need to do many restarts, obviously.